# Erlang regexp vs. re loading issues

Tags: erlang

This is probably something very basic, but my Erlang installation is doggedly rejecting my calls to the [`re` module](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/re.html) with `error:undef`s.  It accepts the [`regexp` package](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/regexp.html), however, so I'm thinking its a version issue.

I'm running v. 5.6.2, and `-import(re, [...]).` at the top of my file, are there any other gotchas I may be missing?  I searched for a fair bit of time, but couldn't find a page describing the minimum version needed.

On a related note, since I'm still pretty fresh to Erlang and its tools/community/dev environments, if you have any suggestions for sites to visit frequently, or tools that changed your dev cycle, please let me know.

Thanks!

EDIT:  If you want to see some code:

```
Erlang (BEAM) emulator version 5.6.2 [source] [smp:2] [async-threads:0] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.6.2  (abort with ^G)
1> re:compile("paul").
** exception error: undefined function re:compile/1

2> regexp:match("paul","au").
{match,2,2}
```

And in my Eunit test:

```
::error:undef
  in function re:compile/1
    called as compile("\\s+")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Erlang installation is very old. It is probably one of pre-R12B releases. The most current stable version is R13B04, and R14 is in beta stage now.

Comment: The never versions actually print out the Erlang version number in the top of the shell. Your old version doesn't do that, though. :-)

Comment: `erlang:system_info(otp_release)` gives you the major version (e.g. `R12B`).  Not sure if you can get the minor version as well...

Answer (score 0):

Try first running your regex code in the Erlang shell and see if you get the same error.
Maybe posting the actual code would help.